# Cannot see phone under 'My Computer'

Tags: usb-connection-mode, mtp

My Galaxy S3 (running CM11) isn't showing at all under My Computer. The phone is set to MTP.

Under my computer the GT-i9300 shows up under 'Unspecified'. When I go into the device properties it shows up as `Google Galaxy Nexus ADB Interface` even though I have debugging mode turned off.

When I try to update the device manually to `MTP USB Device` or `Samsung Mobile MTP Device` I get an error saying *"This device cannot start. (Code 10)"*

I've tried un-installing and re-installing the drivers, as well as the registry tweaks mentioned in [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1797344&page=9) but I do not have the `UpperFilter` key present. I've also tried installing Kies and running the connection troubleshooter with no luck. Any suggestions please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using Android Studio (or another IDE). Try turning on developer mode and then connect the device.

Comment: Thanks, when I run under developer mode it still won't work unfortuantely :(

Comment: @Nick Did you enable USB Debugging? What about verify apps over USB? What happened to me was, I had to wait for an RSA certificate to pop up on my phone to verify that it is connected properly....